# Are "dangling" and "loose" objects the same?

Tags: git, git-gc, git-plumbing, git-fsck

Git's [`fsck` doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) talks about "dangling" objects, while [the `gc` doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) talks only about "loose objects". There's a strict split.

But while skimming a few related SO posts, the terms seem to be used interchangeably. In the [Git Book v2](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery) and Git's source code as well:

```sh
   (main) $ git checkout v2.33.0
(225bc32) $ rg 'dangling (object|commit|blob|tag|tree)' | wc -l
      31
(225bc32) $ rg 'loose (object|commit|blob|tag|tree)' | wc -l
     117
```

Lastly, both commands are often used in sequence, and it seems clear to me from their behavior that they target the same things.

Thus, "dangling" and "loose" are just 2 similar terms for the same concept. Is this summary correct?

---

Or is "loose objects" rather a category, while "dangling" is reserved intentionally for the specific types of objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Loose objects - are those that aren't packed. Git can compress many loose objects into a single pack file.
- Dangling object - is the one that's not referenced by anything (e.g. an orphan commit which has no branch/tag pointing to it). It's garbage that will at some point be collected by GC.
- "Unreachable" object (see comment by @torek). If commit A is a parent of B, then A is not dangling even if B is. Instead A is "unreachable". It's also part of garbage.

Loose object can be dangling, packs can contain dangling objects. So these concepts are orthogonal. But you can create a reference (branch, tag) which will reference a dangling commit and it will stop "dangle".

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was missing: "loose vs. _packed_", but "dangling vs. _referenced_"

Comment: @KatrinLeinweber, nicely said. Though "reachable" is probably a more accurate version of "referenced".

Comment: For chainable objects (commits and trees) Git makes a distinction between "not referenced" / "not reachable", and "dangling". Suppose, e.g., you made commits I-J-K atop existing commit H at the end of branch B. Then you run `git reset B~3` to drop all three new commits: B now points to H, not K. All three are now unreferenced/unreachable, but only one is "dangling" as two *would* be reachable if the "dangling" end were made reachable. (This just shortens the output from git fsck, really.)